Different output in Post request
I'm encountering an issue where my program fails to generate a different output with each new post request. Even when I employ a random function in Python, it consistently produces the same output until I manually restart the process.
I expect a different output each time I make a post request without any manual intervention.
This is my main file
import subprocess
import requests
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from getData.student_data import fetch_student_data
from getData.room_data import fetch_room_data
from getData.teacher_data import fetch_teacher_data
from getData.course_data import fetch_course_data
from getData.curriculum_data import fetch_curriculum_data
from scheduler.CSPAlgorithm import CSPAlgorithm

class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.getData()
    
    def getData(self):
        self.programs = fetch_student_data()
        self.courses = fetch_course_data()
        self.instructors = fetch_teacher_data()
        self.rooms = fetch_room_data()
        self.curriculum = fetch_curriculum_data()
        #print(self.curriculum)
        
    def CSP(self):
        csp = CSPAlgorithm(self.programs, self.courses, self.instructors, self.rooms, self.curriculum)
        result = csp.define_result()
        return result
        
app = Flask(__name__)
class Fetching:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'http://192.168.1.1:8080/Schedule/create'

    def perform_post_request(self, data):
        response = requests.post(self.url, json=data)
        if response.status_code in [200, 201]:
            return response
        else:
            print(f"Error in POST request. Status code: {response.status_code}")
            print(response.text)
            return response

@app.route('/activate_algorithm', methods=['POST'])
def activate_csp_algorithm():
    try:
        scheduler = Scheduler()  # Create a new instance of the Scheduler class for each request
        result = scheduler.CSP()
        
        fetching_instance = Fetching()
        for solution in result:
            response = fetching_instance.perform_post_request(solution)
            print(response.text)
  
        return jsonify({"status": "success", "message": "CSP algorithm activated successfully"})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"status": "error", "message": str(e)})
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
    # scheduler = Scheduler()
    # p = scheduler.CSP()
    # print(p)

I use to do this. but still not the solution
import subprocess

def restart_server():
    print("Restarting server...")
    python = sys.executable
    subprocess.Popen([python, "main.py"])
    sys.exit()

@app.route('/restart_server', methods=['POST'])
def trigger_restart():
    restart_server()
    return jsonify({'message': 'Server restarting...'})



Your old method couldn't possibly work, since restart_server() exits python before calling return jsonify(...)

Why should your request return a different response each time? It calls the same code, and doesn't use any post parameters.
